# Keeping Leading Zeros and appearance of AM/PM when copying and creating a string using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values in a column and create a string in a new sheet in order to copy and paste into a notepad to create a text file.  I am doing this in order to match spacing in the text file.  I have pretty much formatted everything appropriately and but running into two issues when combining the date:

1. There is still an AM and PM in my date
2. Leading zeros are disappearing

I have formatted the cells for the leading zeros using:
WS3.Range("J17").NumberFormat = "000.00"
But this formats it as a custom number and when I copy it it loses the leading zeros.  I have tried formatting a new cell to a text using WS3.Range("K17").NumberFormat = "@" to try and convert it to a text format but it still goes back to the custom format when I paste into the new cell.
[Custom formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXpi5.png)

For the time, i again use a custom format to get the correct time format and in the cell appears the way it should, but the text bar shows the AM and PM and when I use the cells to combine into one string the AM and PM come up again.  WS3.Range("J16").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

[Time format 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n22QS.png)

[string creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkMzK.png)

[Excel text bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDGLk.png)
[Excel cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iTkQ.png)

TIA

Comment: Please, do us (and yourself) a favor and post the code as text, not as image. Images are hard to read and it is not possible to copy it for testing.

Comment: FYI it's relatively straightforward to write directly to a text file, instead of copy/paste between Excel and Notepad.

Answer (score 3):

When you access the content of a cell with VBA using the property `value`, you access the *value*, and a value doesn't contain any formatting.

When you assign a number to a string, VBA will automatically convert that number into a string, using basic rules (no rounding, no leading zeros...).So when you have a cell containing the number 3.14, the string will be "3.14", no matter if you display the number in Excel as `003.14`, `3` (rounded), `$3.14` or any other number format - simply because the value is 3.14. Same is true when assign a date to a string. This is called "implicit" conversion.

There is a way to copy the displayed content of a cell using the property `Text`, eg

```
MeterNumber = WS3.Range("J2").Text
```

However, that has a big disadvantage: If the cell is hidden (because the row or column is hidden), you will get an empty string as response, and if the cell width is too small to display a number (or date) and displays something like `###` instead, you will get this `###` as response.

The best way to get the value formatted as you like is using the VBA function [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications). This function can be used to *explicitly* convert numbers and dates into a string, specifying the formatting rule. It works almost the same as setting the number format in Excel.

```
TestDate = Format(WS3.Range("J15").Value, "HH:mm:ss")
TesterID = Format(WS3.Range("J17").Value, "000.00")
```

You can even use the NumberFormat of the cell itself:

```
TestDate = Format(WS3.Range("J15").Value, WS3.Range("J15").NumberFormat)
TesterID = Format(WS3.Range("J17").Value, WS3.Range("J17").NumberFormat)
```